# Inserting resultset from select and dateadd function into same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, h2

I have "test" table in my H2 database, and i am have some time stamps in that.
I am converting my "_time"  column into normal date using 'DATEADD' function.

And I want result of my select query to get inserted into '_converted_time'

```
sql> select * from test;
| _TIME         | _CONVERTED_TIME
| 1468309423961 | null
| 1468309423962 | null
| 1468308812001 | null
| 1468308815972 | null
(4 rows, 10 ms)
sql> 
sql> 
sql> select DATEADD('SECOND', SUBSTRING(_time,1,10), DATE '1970-01-01') from test;
DATEADD('SECOND', SUBSTRING(EVENT_TIME, 1, 10), DATE '1970-01-01')
2016-07-12 07:43:43.0
2016-07-12 07:43:43.0
2016-07-12 07:33:32.0
2016-07-12 07:33:35.0
```

hence after adding above result into _converted_time it should look like ::

```
sql> select * from test;
| _TIME         | _CONVERTED_TIME
| 1468309423961 | 2016-07-12 07:43:43.0
| 1468309423962 | 2016-07-12 07:43:43.0
| 1468308812001 | 2016-07-12 07:33:32.0
| 1468308815972 | 2016-07-12 07:33:35.0
(4 rows, 10 ms)
```

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Your looking to `update`?

Comment: yes i want to update the table by adding those result set into table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
update test
set CONVERTED_TIME = DATEADD('SECOND', SUBSTRING(_time,1,10), DATE '1970-01-01') 
WHERE CONVERTED_TIME IS NULL;
```

Comment: this query will do same work again and again ....because in future if some _time values get inserted it should resume from where it has left.. can we do this ??